# Find the limit of the following formula.

Tags: calculus

Evaluate:  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}
\frac{x^5 \sin {\frac{1}{x}} + \cos x }{x^2 + x \sin x}$$

I want to ask $\sin \infty $ & $\cos \infty$ equals what? and I am asking if I will use L'hopital's rule?

Comment: Yes, you can use L'Hospital... **if** you can justify it. Can you in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^3\sin(1/x)+\frac{1}{x^2}\cos x}{1+\frac{1}{x}\sin(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^3\sin(1/x)+\frac{1}{x^2}\cos x=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^3\sin(1/x)=\infty$$

Comment: you divided by $x^2$ the denominator and the numerator so in the denominator the term $x \sin x$ becomes $1/x  \sin x$.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks.

Comment: At risk of nit picking, your last step is not entirely clear to me: how you go from $\infty \cdot 0$ to conclude $\infty$, without a series expansion of $\sin(x)$?

Comment: I don't know, but the series expansion works.

Comment: @TeXCub : The last step is justified by writing $x^{2}\cdot x\sin(1/x)$ and noting that $x\sin(1/x)\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$. For such trivial problems one does not need to use Taylor series expansions.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for you to justify and develop:

$$\frac{x^5\sin\frac1x+\cos x}{x^2+x\sin x}\ge\frac{x^4\cfrac{\sin\frac1x}{\frac1x}-1}{x^2+x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

The precise value of sin and cos does not matter here for finding the limit. What matters is that sin and cos remains bounded, i.e., they are always within $[-1,1]$. It is the leading terms in numerator and denominator that dominate and will determine the answer.

Since $|\sin(1/x)| \ll 1$, you can use Taylor series expansion to approximate the first term of the numerator, then take it from there. There are also more specific ways, such as the fact that $x\sin(1/x) = \sin(1/x)/(1/x)$ approaches $1$ when $x$ approaches infinity, but series expansion is more generally applicable with other functions too.

Comment: its also important that $\sin$ is continuous at $0$ and $\sin(0)\neq 0$

Comment: @Jorge: limits are concerned with values in the neighbourhood of (not at) the limit abscissa, so I don't think $\sin(0)$ is relevant here. Rather, the dominant functional dependence of $x^5 \sin(1/x)$ on $x$ for large $x$ matters. But maybe this is what you meant.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean, more concisely I should have said $\lim \limits_{x\to 0 } \sin (x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I don't understand your last comment's limit: it certainly is true that $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\sin x=0\;$ ...

Comment: oh yeah, I need another step